# When does "/bin/rm" removes itself while issuing "rm -rfv / " command?

Tags: linux, kernel, rm

When files are being deleted after issuing `/bin/rm -rfv /` command as root, how does `rm` continue to run even after `/bin` has been deleted? How does the kernel deal with this file system process?

Answer (score 2):

Files only get really deleted after they are no longer in use.

So if you started a process, such as `less somefile.txt` and then `rm somefile.txt` you could still continue scrolling down in the running `less` that still has a file handle.

Even if that were not the case, the `rm` program would already be completely in RAM while it is running. There is nothing that would check whether the original file is still there or not.

For traditional binaries this is not a problem, for scripting languages that are interpreted on the fly it may be different, as the interpreter (say, `bash` for a shell script) may re-check file contents.